# Creating a debian package that copies a file to the .config directory

Tags: installation, package, debian, config

The .config directory can be found in the user's folder (/user/home/{username}/config) and here I want a file to be copied during installation. In the install file, what route should I type, as the username is different on each computer? I tried with `~/.config/program_name` but it creates a *~* folder at the root level of the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates the file for root because the installation is running by the root user and therefore `~` expands to `/root`.

I don't expect the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) to allow installing files in home directories. The best reason against this is that you might add a new user after installation of the package. Who should create the file?

Of course there are hackish ways to do it using a [postinstall](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts) script and the folder [`/etc/skel`](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html) folder but IMO the best solution is that the program itself should look for them on every startup and create them if necessary.

Comment: Where should it install a global config file, then? In which folder do programs usually install some global default config files? Thanks

Comment: `/etc/yourprogram.config` and|or `/etc/yourprogram` (as a directory) might be appropriate locations. Check the Linux [File System Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) standard which is a subset of the Linux Standards Base (LSB)